# install virtualbox through kickstart centos 7

Tags: centos, virtualbox, kickstarter

I am trying fully automate my os installation. I need certain packages to be installed during this automation. I am specifying all the required packages names in the kickstart file, for ex:

```
%%packages    
php
php-mysql
httpd
```

similarly, I am trying to install **virtualbox** through kickstart installation.

I manually downloaded the **virtualbox rpm** `VirtualBox-5.0-5.0.0_101573_el7-1.x86_64.rpm`, and placed it inside the Package folder of centos7 and recreated repo.

Now my packages list in kickstart file is :

```
%%packages 
VirtualBox
```

But this throws an error during installation

`you have specified that the package VirtualBox should be installed, this package doesn't exist`

I have no clue, what's wrong here? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualbox has weird and unconventional package tags in its spec file. If you look at its name:

```
VirtualBox-5.0-5.0.0_101573_el7-1.x86_64.rpm
```

then you notice its version is `5.0.0_101573_el7` (very poor convention) and its release is `1` (missing `el7`).

Therefore, its package name is actually `VirtualBox-5.0`, so you need to specify

```
%%packages 
VirtualBox-5.0
```

in your kickstart.